# Propagate V=s Flage to all sub makefiles

Tags: c, module, makefile, linux-kernel

When ever I build kernel modules using `make`, I get this kind of logs

```
CC[M] module1
CC[M] module2
CC[M] module3
CC[M] module4
```

i.e just compilation or linking info about any module currently being processed.

**I need to know complete information that which commands actually compiles the modules source code, what are the `flags` used in those command etc.** e.g

```
gcc -Wall abcd.c
```

I even checked it by setting `V=s` , `V=1`, `-n` and `-d` but couldn't get what I want.

Kindly tell me how to make `V=s` propagate through each and every subsequent makefiles. It could be done by `exporting`, by how?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two kinds of methods:

1. You can build modules with "`make V=1`" to print verbose messages.
2. You can also do this by putting "`export KBUILD_VERBOSE=1`" line into your Makefile.

Here is an example of makefile:

```
TARGET  :=sysfs-sample

export KBUILD_VERBOSE=1

obj-m += $(TARGET).o

$(TARGET)-objs  := main.o

MODULE_DIR  := "$(PWD)"

all:
    CROSS_COMPILE= ARCH=x86 make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(MODULE_DIR) modules 

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(MODULE_DIR) clean
```

Comment: `make V=1` do not show the compilation or building commands with flags. I have tried it. exporting KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 solve the problem? Can it modify the builtin Makefile in linux kernel for doing so?

Comment: I think your kernel's root Makefile modified. Please refer to mainline kernel's comments. [link](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/+/master/Makefile#43)

Comment: That what I did bro yesterday, I modified the same file by placing `KBUILD_VERBOSE=1` before `ifndef` conditional.