# Steps involved in compiling linux driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

For an application to be compiled on Linux the steps involved are:

```
Pre-processing->Compilation->Assembly->Linking.
```

What are the steps involved in compiling a kernel driver? Are the steps different if I compile the driver as a built-in module vs a module vs using custom `Makefile`?

Comment: Just build module with verbose messages and see what is happened. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34428930/3440745) about verbose module's build.

Answer (score 1):

Right same steps are followed for device driver in Linux :-

**Pre-processing->Compilation->Assembly->Linking.**

These are basic steps need to followed every where , no matter how one follow.

Regarding  built-in module vs a module vs using custom Makefile :: -

Device drivers can be compiled with whole kernel and device driver is part of  kernel image means device driver is statically linked with the kernel. When device driver is statically linked with kernel and its loaded at boot up.

When device driver is compiled as module , then this module is not part of kernel image and  can be loaded in system on the fly.

When device driver is part of kernel image , this device driver source files compiled as normal file of kernel source tree.

For example sample.c has device driver code and CONFIG_SAMPLE config macros controlling its compilation then include following line in Makefile

```
Config-($CONFIG_SAMPLE)   = sample.o
```

When value of config macro is y , the driver gets compiled with kernel image and when its value is n then , then device driver don’t get compiled.

Device drivers as a module can be compiled using following commands.

```
make -C path/of/kernel    path/of/driver/in/kernel/folder/module.ko
```